# How to handle/select all checkboxes - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to handle my select all function , but at the moment i got some issues .I'm trying to fill an object with all check boxes . Can somebody give me a hand ?

This is my function to handle single checkbox :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { docList:{} }

 handleCheckboxClick = (e) => {
    let parsedVal = JSON.parse(e.target.value);
    let newDocList = { ...this.state.docList };
    if (e.target.checked) {
        newDocList[parsedVal.documentId] = parsedVal.documentNumber;
    } else {
        delete newDocList[parsedVal.documentId];
    }
    this.setState({
        docList: newDocList,
    }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.docList)
    });
};
```

The render :

```
 <MaterialTable options={{

               showSelectAllCheckbox:false,
               selection: true,
               selectionProps: rowData => ({
               onClick: (event , rowData) => this.handleCheckboxClick(event,rowData),
               value: JSON.stringify({ documentId: rowData.documentId, documentNumber: rowData.documentNumber })
                            }),
```

And this is handle select all :

```
 handleAllCheckboxes = (e) => {
   if(e.target.value){
       this.setState(state=> ({selected: state.data.map(rowData=> rowData.documentId) 
       }))
       console.log(this.state.selected)
       return;
   }
   this.setState({ selected: [] });
}
```

And the render :

```
<Checkbox
    onClick={this.handleAllCheckboxes}
    indeterminate
    /> Select All
```

Comment: So, I would use refs for this. So each input would have a ref attribute (kind of like the name attribute) and then loop them.

var fields = this.refs;

That will pick up all the input items with refs and then you need to get all the checkboxes from that.

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: I thought about it also . Actually if i do `console.log(this.state.uniqueIDS)` inside the `handleAllCheckboxes`  i got an Array of all documents from my previous response from the BE

Answer (score -2):

Included an example of select all or deselect all.  Alternatively, click one at a time :)
https://codesandbox.io/s/select-deselect-checkboxes-jugl2

Comment: Feel free to comment on why this is a poor example. I was only trying to provide some assistance.

Comment: I didn't try it out . And i didn't vote on it negative .

Comment: No worries. Any feedback is welcomed. Thank you. Hope you got your checkboxes working!

Comment: Not at the moment but i am still trying .

Comment: My example might not be your exact solution.  Although, it might help your project by looking at how my select all / deselect all works.. Just a thought.  All good either way.